# Crystal Report Problem with rtl language and slash contained string

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, .net-2.0

I use Crystal Reports to get different reports.
I am using asp.net 2.0 and crystal Report version 10
The problem is that some of the commodity names in the system are a combination of letters, numbers, and characters that are correctly represented within the system, but when outputting Crystal Reports in print or PDF or during preview, the numbers before and after The slash characters are intertwined.
Fro example: گیج رینگی 20*1/4
it will show as : گیج رینگی ‏20‏*‏1‏/‏4‏ 
Horizontal Alignment in format object of my .Rpt file should be Right and Reading Order in paragraph tab sheet should be "Right to Left" because of my Persian language that is RTL.

is there anybody who now what i should be do for this problem?

[in System:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T43sJ.png)

[in Crystal Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbhYX.png)

[in pdf export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5ckq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please provide sample RTF text (the raw text, not the resulting text).
Or a sample rpt with a formula containing the RTF text.